# Нужен аналог команды "rpm -Uvh", только на dpkg

Tags: linux, dpkg, rpm

В файловой системе(не в репозитории), есть два файла *.deb одной программы с разной версией, старее и новее соответственно.

Сначала ставлю струю версию потом, надо не удаляя её(напрямую), накатить, как бы, по верх новую.

В эрпэмах это делается одной командой:
"rpm -Uvh <файл>... – обновить пакет(ы), если не установлены – установить"

Есть ли подобная команда на дэбах?

(погуглил, не помогло)

Comment: `dpkg -i` нужнобольшесимволов

Comment: не, не ставит, ругается на конфликт старой и новой версии. "rpm -i" ведёт себя аналогично на rpm'ах

Comment: *ругается на конфликт старой и новой версии* — это очень интересно, на абсолютно неинформативно. приложите, пожалуйста, вывод команды к тексту вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: Откуда вы знаете, что новая версия действительно новее?

Comment: @0andry Я это точно знаю, я знаю это приложение, это своего рода тест. И опять же есть аналогичные два пакета на rpm'ах(.rpm). 'rpm -i' не ставит, "rpm -Uvx" ставит как бы по верх, это мне и надо только в дэбах с дэб-паетами